# Consistent no route to host errors on servers

Tags: router, firewall, troubleshooting

Servers configured with DHCP have a default route in the corporate network. Every time a "new" host is connected, a "no route to host error" is received. The second request after a few seconds works fine. This happens most frequently on port 443.

How can this be fixed, as the firewall used is a checkpoint firewall and there is no further information in the log files. Is there a linux command to trace the error constantly, as this only happens every time the host is unkown.

As I am not an Network engineer I just need a way to gather more information for the specialists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reason this may happen.

- The switch to which the new host is connected could have STP enabled
  on the access interface, and it is going through the STP
  initialization (blocking, listening, learning, forwarding). You don't
  detail the switch model, but you can skip the process on Cisco
  switches by enabling `portfast`.
- The new host doesn't yet have anything in it ARP cache, so it must
  use ARP to discover the layer-2 address of its target. You often see
  this on a new host when you ping: there will be one or two
  unsuccessful pings before it starts to work.